# Bluetooth reciever as wifi dongle

Tags: bluetooth

I have a spare wireless mouse and am wondering if I can use its receiver for receiving wifi signals for my router instead. Do any of you know if this is possible and how I might achieve it

Comment: The answer to your question is absolutely not.  WiFi and Bluetooth share almost nothing in common.

Comment: i before e, expect after c

Answer (score 1):

They're different protocols using different frequencies. You cannot use a BT adapter hardware to communicate with WiFi signals.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Bluetooth and Wi-Fi have very little in common except for using same spectrum. The technology behind isn't compatible.